# ImageMagick Mogrify Compress Images Recursively

Tags: command-line, compression, imagemagick, image-manipulation, mogrify

Windows 10. ImageMagick v7.1.0-62

I need to compress and optimise a lot of .jpg images using ImageMagick. I am using the following command, which is working (this overwrites the original files which is what I want).

I run this in the windows command line when in the required folder (e.g. `folder 1`)

```
magick morgify -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -strip -quality 50 -interlace Plane *.jpg
```

The issue is this command only handles a single folder at a time. how can I change this so it runs recursively from my root folder through all sub folders.

My file structure is below;

```
- images
- - folder 1
- - - folder 1a
- - - folder 1b
- - folder 2
- - folder 3
- - - folder 3a
- - - folder 3b
```

Comment: [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill could you provide me an example of how I could apply this to my current command please?

Comment: There are examples in the link I gave you.

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't seem to get it working recursively through folders - only individual ones. Maybe there's a limitation with using `morgify ` in a for loop, perhaps I need a custom script. I'll keep investigating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop directories. In PowerShell it's as simple as:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | % { mogrify -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -strip -quality 50 -interlace Plane "$($_.FullName)/*.jpg" }
```

It gets all the subdirectories, then uses `ForEach-Object` (`%`) to go through returned results and calls `mogrify` command for each.

Note that `mogrify` will throw an error if one of the subdirectories doesn't have any jpgs, but the command will continue for all subdirectories regardless.

It also doesn't include the folder where you're calling the command, but you can create a `.ps1` script with the code above and include also `mogrify -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -strip -quality 50 -interlace Plane *.jpg` command in it to run it there, then execute the script.